# How to write storde procedure for 52weeks data?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

My requirement is to return the 52 weeks data based on "sales" column.
if sales column having no data on particular week  have to display the o.oo amount ,

This is my exact requirement:

In my table i have week-no :week:1,week:2..etc are available and week date i.e 1-1-2013 to 7-1-2013 etc are available and amount columns with week amount for example week:1 amount:300; here i am displaying week no one below for graph and week amount on y-axis but when amount is not available in amount column the week-no is not displaying in graph i want to display week-no with zero(0) amount. for this i need stored procedure and i am using kendo-chart

how to write stored procedure can any one help me please?

Comment: Can you provide sample input data and the format of output you are expecting?

Comment: Can you provide some indication of effort on your part?

Comment: hi thank you for reply in my table i have week-no :week:1,week:2..etc are available and week date i.e 1-1-2013 to 7-1-2013 etc are available and amount columns with week amount for example week:1 amount:300;    here i am displaying week no one below for graph and week amount on y-axis but when  amount is not  available in amount column the week-no is not displaying in graph i want to display week-no with zero(0) amount. for this i need stored procedure and i am using kendo-chart.

Comment: hi every if my question is not understandable tell me i will tell more clearly but please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually the best solution for these types of rollups is to have a custom 'calendar' table that is pre-populated with all dates/date ranges that you application may ever require. You set it up once, it stays relatively small (even 100 years worth of dates is only going to have 36,500 rows) and by adding attributes to the calendar table you can accommodate almost any type of date related query you can imagine.

In this way, any type of date-related rollup or query you want to do, you can join to your calendar table and all available dates/date ranges can be pulled in.